# Firestore interferes with animation

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, animation, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some issues with my Swift project. It seems like Firestore functions are interfering with the animation I'm trying to perform in a cell.

### My goal

[This animation of a progress bar going from 0.0 to 1.1 inside a UITableViewCell (screenrecord)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzyec74us0habio/Screen%20Recording%202020-08-22%20at%2018.20.25.mov?dl=0)

### Actual result

Currently, the animation isn't working. The progress bar *is* updating, but not animating. [It looks like this now.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gys12l7n8khvbvf/Screen%20Recording%202020-08-22%20at%2018.23.35.mov?dl=0)

### The problem

Both the goal and the actual result have the same animation code placed in `TaskCell.swift`. `startAnimation()` gets called when the box is clicked together with `startActionII()`.

```
@IBAction func checkBoxAction(_ sender: Any) {
    startActionII()
    startAnimation()
}

func startAnimation() {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0) {
        self.progressBar.setProgress(1.0, animated: true)
    }
}


func startActionII() {
    if items![indexRow!].checked {
        delegate?.changeButton(state: false, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID)
    } else {
        delegate?.changeButton(state: true, indexSection: indexSection!, indexRow: indexRow!, itemID: itemID)
    }
}
```

Here's where the problem is. The delegate method gets called correctly: all print statements & Firestore updates work. But, the Firestore code seems to interfere with the animation. When I use the code seen below as `changeButton()`, the animation doesn't work. However, when I replace all the Firestore code with a print statement, the animations do work. This is my `changeButton` delegate method.

```
func changeButton(state: Bool, indexSection: Int?, indexRow: Int?, itemID: String?) {
    
    print("Doing logic II...")
    
    sections[indexSection!].items[indexRow!].checked = state

    let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
    generator.impactOccurred()

    if let itemID = itemID {
        let itemRef = db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sections).document("\(indexSection!)").collection(K.FStore.items).document(itemID)



         if sections[indexSection!].items[indexRow!].checked {
            itemRef.updateData([
                 K.Item.isChecked: true,
                 K.Item.checkedBy: currentUserID!,
                 K.Item.dateChecked: Date()
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }

            print("hello")


                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
                        print("Moving item to itemsChecked...")

                        if let indexSection = indexSection, let indexRow = indexRow {
                                                            let item = self.sections[indexSection].items[indexRow]

                            // Item's properties variables
                            let itemID: String
                            let name: String
                            let uid: String
                            let isChecked: Bool
                            let checkedBy: String
                            let dateCreated: Date
                            let dateChecked: Date

                            let itemRef = self.db.collection(K.FStore.lists).document(self.currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sections).document("\(indexSection)").collection(K.FStore.items).document(item.itemID!)

                            itemRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
                                if let document = document, document.exists {
                                    let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"


                                    // Get the properties of the item
                                    let name = document.data()?[K.Item.name] as? String
                                    let uid = document.data()?[K.Item.uid] as? String
                                    let category = document.data()?[K.Item.categoryNumber] as? Int
                                    let isChecked = document.data()?[K.Item.isChecked] as? Bool
                                    let dateCreated = document.data()?[K.Item.date] as? Date
                                    let dateChecked = document.data()?[K.Item.dateChecked] as? Date
                                    let checkedBy = document.data()?[K.Item.checkedBy] as? String

                                    var ref: DocumentReference? = nil

                                    // Save the properties of the item in sectionsDeleted
                                    ref = self.db.collection(K.lists).document(self.currentListID!).collection(K.FStore.sectionsChecked).document("\(category!)").collection(K.FStore.items).addDocument(data: [
                                            K.Item.name: name,
                                            K.Item.isChecked: isChecked,
                                            K.Item.categoryNumber: category,
                                            K.Item.date: dateCreated,
                                            K.Item.dateChecked: dateChecked,
                                            K.Item.checkedBy: checkedBy,
                                            K.Item.uid: uid,
                                            K.Item.dateDeleted: Date()
                                    ]) { err in
                                        if let err = err {
                                            print("Error adding document: \(err)")
                                        } else {

                                            // If successfull, delete the item in the normal collection
                                            itemRef.delete() { err in
                                                if let err = err {
                                                    print("Error removing document: \(err)")
                                                } else {
                                                    print("Document successfully removed!")
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    print("Document does not exist")
                                }
                            }

                            self.tableView.reloadData()

        } else {
            itemRef.updateData([
                K.Item.isChecked : false
            ]) { err in
                if let err = err {
                    print("Error writing document: \(err)")
                } else {
                    print("Document successfully written!")
                }
                            }
    }
                } } } }

    refreshTable()
}
```

Could anyone help me on how to fix this issue?

Many thanks,
Matt

[GitHub link](https://github.com/mattttis/Carrot) & [Link to branch 'MoveSections'](https://github.com/mattttis/Carrot/tree/MoveSections)

Comment: I downloaded the project but cant find this code there, what branch? did you commit the changes?

Comment: @Alex.Pinhasov, you're right, sorry. [This is the link to the branch](https://github.com/mattttis/Carrot/tree/MoveSections). The latest commit is called 'Stackoverflow' on the branch 'MoveSections'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few problems in your project

1. google info plist is in the wrong path, you created a reference to is but you should have copied it to your project path.

[image]

I cant build the project because I am missing the google info plist like I mentioned

*Edit

Look at what you did here you

You invoke "startActionII()" and change the model boolean status, which is fine, then inside that async block, you call reload data on your table view.

you have conflicting UI behaviors, from one hand you are trying to show a progress bar with animation and AT THE SAME TIME (almost it's async) you are reloading the entire table view and overriding your animation.

What you are doing is problematic since your UI is interactive meaning the click the user makes affect the DB immediately and not at the end of the process, so what is the purpose of the progress animation?

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the GitHub repo so it should include the plist file now. I'm a complete beginner when it comes to DispatchQueue and async/sync so I'm struggling with that. The purpose of the animation is that the user has a 5-second chance to undo the checkBoxAction after which the cell disappears.

Comment: So what you should do is the following:
1. Start the progress animation + updating the model
2. Set a timer OR animation completion block to know when 5 seconds passed
3. If the user didn't undo his choice, only then make the firebase DB call
4. Remember this - if you are expecting a change in a single cell find that cell and update the UI for him or alternatively which is prefered way, use update cell for index path instead of reloading the entire table.